# Split a float in pre-determined amount that adds up together to be the float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, division

I am looking to create a script that basically does the following:-

- Split a given float into x amounts of floats (particularly into different values)
- Each value must be an increment of 0.05 (eg 2.65, 1.25, 18.50)
- The x amounts of floats must add up to be the given float

IE it should look like this:

```
Total float = 2.50
Amount of splits = 2
New float array = [2, 0.50]

or

Total float = 4.00
Amount of splits = 4
New float array = [1, 2, 0.25, 0.75]
```

I have not been able to try much at the moment. I have been trying to think of a way to make it work but I am unsure of the best way to do it.

EDIT: I was able to make some progress but I have one small issue where some times if the number I'm using is too small, it will add a 0 or two in the list which I do not want.

```
public void SplitWinnings()
{
    splitAmounts = new float[loseThreshold - 1];
    while(splitAmounts.Sum() < totalWinAmount)
    {
        int rng = Random.Range(0, splitAmounts.Length);
        splitAmounts[rng] += 0.05f;
        splitAmounts[rng] = Mathf.Round(splitAmounts[rng] * 100f) / 100f;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), of which there are many variations. If you multiply all input values by 20, it can be restated in integer form. These problems are typically solved by dynamic programming. Much depends on whether you need *any* solution, *some* solution subject to specific constraints, or *all* solutions; depending on your scenario [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) may be another feasible approach -- while probably overkill for a problem like this, there are many existing packages for it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @JeroenMostert Where would I start with this? Mainly the split into random numbers of 0.05 denomination?

Comment: Define "random". :P For example, one feasible "solution" to split 4 into 4 parts is `[4, 0, 0, 0]`. Even if you disregard 0 as valid this still leaves trivial solutions like `[3.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]`. A simple "random" approach can be done through divide and conquer: to split a number `N` into `p` parts, generate a random number `0 < x < N`, then solve the problem for `N - x` and `p - 1` parts until you are left "splitting" a number into 1 part.

Comment: From what I understand, there should not be any 0s in the array. But I also believe that no two values should be the same. I may be wrong but the task simply says "split the total into smaller amounts" and nothing else. But being a casino style game, I'm assuming there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: That isn't hard; you just add an extra check to see if the number you picked randomly is already part of the solution and if so, retry. More sophisticated approaches are possible by reducing this to a true subset sum problem -- generate *all* numbers in 0.05 increments between 0.05 and `N` (or rather represent them as a bit array), then solve the problem of picking exactly `p` numbers that sum to `N`. But unless the number of parts is very large, this is likely to have much worse performance than just retrying.

Comment: Also, because exact calculations with floating-point values are awkward, if the `0.05` is fixed the problem is more conveniently solved by multiplying everything by 20 and using integers, then dividing the solution values by 20, as mentioned before.

Comment: I just edited my main post. I have been able to get somewhere with the solution. Is there a way to make sure 0 is not added to the array?

Comment: You can simply initialize all values in your array to `0.05`. Although it's worth pointing out that your current solution is very inefficient for large values of `totalWinAmount`, as you are only approaching it in steps of `0.05`. Splitting up, say, 1M this way requires 20M iterations no matter how many parts there are (with each iteration re-calculating a sum), which is much worse than necessary. For small values it's doable.

Comment: It's only supposed to go up to 8 values so I waaaaaant to say it works. Also I added a check to see if it is higher than 0 then add it in. But it works out! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75726952/7111561) using Linq `Sum` is extremely inefficient!

You can already improve this a lot by a factor of about 3 by simply keeping track of the sum yourself directly without always iterating the entire array over and over again. Simply keep track of exactly the amount you add or remove from the array:

```
public void SplitWinnings()
{
    // Keep track of the sum yourself!
    // You already know how much you add each time!
    var sum = 0f;

    splitAmounts = new float[loseThreshold - 1];
    while(sum < totalWinAmount)
    {
        int rng = Random.Range(0, splitAmounts.Length);
        splitAmounts[rng] += minIncrement;
        // also keep track of the sum
        sum += minIncrement;

        float splitFloat = (Mathf.Round(splitAmounts[rng] * 100f) / 100f);

        if (splitFloat > 0)
        {
            // remove the previous value
            sum -= splitAmounts[rng];

            splitAmounts[rng] = splitFloat;

            // track the new value
            sum += splitFloat;
        }
    }
}
```

However, you still do a lot of rounding and might end up with invalid iterations which means throwing away performance.

I would even go further and simply beforehand calculate the maximum required multiples of your `0.05` increment, iterate a fixed amount -> you know exactly how many elements you need to fill beforehand and then do all the rest of the calculation in `int`.

Doing this I improved the time by a factor of 100!

```
public void SplitWinnings()
{
    // calculate how many of your minIncrements you need in total
    var totalMultiples = Mathf.RoundToInt(totalWinAmount / minIncrement);
    // while iterating will keep track of how many multiples you have remaining
    var remainingMultiples = totalMultiples;

    // Not sure why but you seem to require -1 here
    var splitCount = loseThreshold - 1;
    splitAmounts = new float[splitCount];
    
    // instead of while have a fixed amount of iterations
    // namely exactly for all return elements except the last one
    for(var i = 0; i < splitCount - 1; i++)
    { 
        // reducing the remaining array elements => save up at least 1 multiple for each array element
        var maxMultiples = remainingMultiples - (splitCount - i);
        // use at least one multiple per element
        // have to add +1 again since upper bound for int is exclusive but we want to use it up
        var multiples = Random.Range(1, maxMultiples + 1);
        
        // after calculating the multiples in int multiply again by the minIncrement to get according float value
        splitAmounts[i] = multiples * minIncrement;
        
        // and reduce the remaining multiples accordingly
        remainingMultiples -= multiples;
    }
    
    // The last item is just filled with whatever is left
    splitAmounts[splitCount - 1] = remainingMultiples * minIncrement;
}
```

See [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K6MRfy) for comparing

Comment: I love this response! Thank you for your help. This looks great!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for lower amounts of split values as @Jeroen Mostert had mentioned. But practically what I am looking for. :)

```
public void SplitWinnings()
{
    splitAmounts = new float[loseThreshold - 1];
    while(splitAmounts.Sum() < totalWinAmount)
    {
        int rng = Random.Range(0, splitAmounts.Length);
        splitAmounts[rng] += minIncrement;

        float splitFloat = (Mathf.Round(splitAmounts[rng] * 100f) / 100f);

        if (splitFloat > 0)
        {
            splitAmounts[rng] = splitFloat;
        }
    }
}
```